# Como fazer um rodapé fixo e retrátil similar a página de Economia do portal Terra?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu tenho a ideia de construir um rodapé fixo na página similar ao do portal Terra de Economia. Tal funcionalidade vai me permitir expor um chat neste espaço.

Gosto da solução do Terra porque é possível retrair o objeto e ainda manter o mesmo no canto direito inferior sem atrapalhar a leitura da página.

Preciso saber o nome da propriedade e tecnologias envolvidas.

http://economia.terra.com.br/

Comment: CSS com `display: fixed` e JS para ocultar e exibir, além das duas imagens das setas...

Comment: Existe uma propriedade a respeito? encontrei uma solução chamada "sticky footer" mas ainda falta resolver o problema da barra retrátil.

Answer (score 2):

Crie um footer com um `id="rodape"` e depois coloque no css:
html:

```
 <footer id="rodape"><a style="position: relative; right: 0px; float:left; font-size: 50px; display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; " href="javascript:drop('fechar')" id="link"><span> < </span></a>
</footer>
```

css:

```
  #rodape{
    margin-bottom:0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: #333333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  }
```

o `width: 100%` e o `height: 50px` são opcionais.
Se você não quiser um um `width: 100%` alinha-se com o `left:`.

script para esconder/aparecer

```
    function drop(ver){
    if(ver == "fechar"){
        document.getElementById('rodape').style.left = "-97%";
        document.getElementById('link').style.float = "right";
        document.getElementById('link').href = "javascript:drop('abrir')";
        document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = ">";
    }if(ver == "abrir"){
        document.getElementById('rodape').style.left = "0px";
        document.getElementById('link').style.float = "left";
        document.getElementById('link').href = "javascript:drop('fechar')";
        document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = "<";
    }
}
```

E para aparecer quando o usuário está no fim este link pode lhe ajudar http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/create-stay-on-top-menu-css3-jquery/

Comment: Falta a parte do recolher/expandir

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `.animate()` do JQuery para esconder o mostrar o rodapé

Segue um exemplo:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3oLoN/PDVLC/2/)